# File.ReadAllBytes returns an empty array

Tags: c#, .net, file, unity-game-engine, byte

I'm writing a game in C# in Unity 3D (.NET 2.0). To read external files I use **File.ReadAllBytes**. However, today I encountered a problem one of the files that is clearly not an empty file no corrupted is not read properly - ReadAllBytes returns a byte array with zero elements. The file I'm trying to read is an MP3 file and I could not see anything wrong with it. I can load it in FMODEx, I can play it with a media player, yet ReadAllBytes returns zero. This only happens on that particular file but I'm sure that if it happens with it, then there might be a lot of other files that won't get read.

What can be causing **File.ReadAllBytes** to malfunction like that and what is the best workaround for this thing ? (eg. if an empty array is returned, read the file in another manner).

Added Code as poster cannot yet:

```
public void LoadFrom(string filePath) 
{
    StopTransfer();
    byte[] bytes = null;
    if (File.Exists(filePath)) 
    {
        path = filePath;
        name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
        extension = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
        bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        if (bytes.Length == 0) bytes = ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        if (bytes.Length == 0) error = "Corrupt file";
        fullFile = bytes;
    } 
    else 
    {
        fullFile = null;
        error = "Not found";
    }
}
```

Comment: post your code and the filename, possibly it's as simple as a filename mismatch. If it's on mobile consider that file system may be case sensitive as in iOS.

Comment: I agree with the answer below. if you are catching exceptions somewhere it may be you dont see the exception. Hard to guess without code, or good error reporting.

Comment: @ LearnCocos2D: windows file systems are not case sensitive.

Comment: i know but op did not indicate the target platform(s)

Comment: Hi, it can't be a filename mismatch because I'm using a browser to pick the file. Here's the code:
 public void LoadFrom(string filePath){
  StopTransfer();
  byte[] bytes = null;
  if (File.Exists (filePath)) {
   path = filePath;
   name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
   extension = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
   bytes = File.ReadAllBytes (filePath);
   if(bytes.Length == 0) bytes = ReadAllBytes(filePath);
   if(bytes.Length == 0) error = "Corrupt file";
   fullFile = bytes;
  } else{ 
   fullFile = null;
   error = "Not found";
  }

 }
The platform is PC.